# Split text in text file into lines

Tags: python-3.x

I need to split a text file into lines.

I imported the text file into python but print(readline()) prints the whole file.

```
with open('laxdaela_saga.en.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

I eventually need to count unique words in the text file and other stats, but one step is to divide into lines. This is the step I'm dealing with.

Comment: can you show us some lines of your text file?

Comment: Is it this file? https://sagadb.org/files/text/laxdaela_saga.en.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` function of Python. It splits the given string into an array based on some pattern.
In your case, the pattern will be newline `\n`.
so `split('\n')` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('laxdaela_saga.en.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x = line.split()
        print(x)
```

Hope this will be of your help.